# Delphi DCOM client server application, on close of server gives 'system Error 1400. Invalid window handle'

Tags: delphi, client-server, dcom, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am working on a client server application in delphi 10.2.2 where DCOM connection is used.
The server application had a tlb file use which has GUID in it.
When the client application is execute the server application starts and when client application is closed the server is also closed and thereby the following error is raised  **'system Error 1400. Invalid window handle'.**

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOMGe.png)

Trying to find out how Server application is triggerred from Client exe when Tdcomconnection.connected is set to true.
If possible please share a link which has got COM Client and server application working

I have added the image of the message, on click of cancel I get
**'system Error 1400. Invalid window handle'.**
First this message is displayed.

on server side there is only one tlb file used.I do not know how it is created.
I am freasher to DCOM so please guide me.

Comment: In which application is the error raised, the client or the server?

Comment: @MartynA the error is raised server side. Once I close the client application.

Comment: So, have you tried running the server in the Delphi debugger?

Comment: @MartynA yes I tried Running the server in delphi debugger. however this error is encountered(server side)after we close the client application, somewhere there is a trigger where  server closed after some time.

Comment: @MartynA I have added few more details with the error message.Please check the error message attached.

Comment: No thanks.  I gave up working with DCom 20 years ago.

Comment: @MartynA  Please guide me here if you have any idea about this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to try to guess what code you have in your client and server.  Add their code to your q and maye someone will be prepared to look into it.   You need to include an MCVE(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)